# JSF Custom Servlet Mapping To a File

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, servlets, jsf-2

below code is used to map urls with /photos pattern to a /photos.jsp,since `<jsp-file>` tag is not valid in jsf, so how can i do this kind of mapping with jsf?
i need this for two reasons :

1- hide my underlying structure at least from naked eyes

2-simplify urls

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>photos</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/photos.jsp</jsp-file>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>photos</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/photos</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> hide my underlying structure at least from naked eyes

Anything in the `WEB-INF` folder cannot be accessed outside from your server.

> simplify urls

Insert the folllowing code your `faces-config.xml` it will redirect everything from `/photo*` to `/photo.jsp`.

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/photo*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <to-view-id>/photo.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Urls are supposed to be mapped to a JSF controller component (servlet or filter), not to a jsp file as expressed in the question. Below describes that `photos.jsp` and urls under `/photo` are mapped to the custom servlet `Photo.java` :

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>photos</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>package.Photos</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>photos</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/photos.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>photos</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/photos/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```